# Refering to a predefined range through r1c1 formulation

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, named-ranges

I have to look up some values from another range in another worksheet. I have defined the range as "x", and i would like to use it in the r1c1 formulation, see example:

```
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("ark1").Range("A1:d400")
With twb.Sheets(filename)
        .Range("k2:k" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],x,4,False)"
        .Range("l2:l" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11],x,4,False)"
```

I have tried to do the application.vlookup, which works, but too slow, as i have to loop through 4000+ rows twice
I will need to use the range x, as the range should be flexible depending on the lookup table, exmaple:

```
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("ark1").Range("A1:d" & rows)
```

Any suggestions how i can refer to the range x in my lookup function?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume the fact you are putting the exact same formula in both columns is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `x` range as `Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("ark1").Range("A1:d400")` , and you want to use it in a formula in `R1C1` type, you can get the address from your `x` range by `x.Address(False, False, xlR1C1)`.

Try using the 2 lines below:

```
.Range("K2:K" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10]," & x.Address(False, False, xlR1C1) & ",4,False)"
.Range("L2:L" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11]," & x.Address(False, False, xlR1C1) & ",4,False)"
```

Following @Rory comment and PO, if you are referring to an external workbook then you need to add a 4th parameter, and also to look for absolute range:

```
.Range("K2:K" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10]," & x.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",4,False)"
.Range("L2:L" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11]," & x.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",4,False)"
```

Comment: It looks like the range is in a different workbook, so you'll need the `External:=True` argument too.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes, i guess i will have to use the external=True, as it currently gives me following in the sheet: (cell a3) " =Vlookup(A3;K3:N402;4;FALSE)"

Comment: Almost, the sheet is the right one, however the referred range is still K2:N401 instead of A1:d400. also i would need the X range to be fixed like $A$1:$D$400, as it's a table i'm looking up in

Comment: @KMO then use `x.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)`

Comment: @KMO try edited code now, modified to check Absolute Range

Comment: THanks a lot! The final code looks like this: 
     .Range("K2:K" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10]," & x.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",4,False)"

            
            .Range("L2:L" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11]," & x.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",3,False)"